# EF Core long running streaming query with IAsyncEnumerable throws exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iasyncenumerable

I'm writing vary large tables to CSV files using `IAsyncEnumerable` to stream the rows from the database to my application, doing some modifications and then writing them into a CSV file stream.

The tables contain a lot of rows, so the queries are running for hours.
Quite often I see exceptions like this one:

> System.InvalidOperationException Invalid attempt to call
> CheckDataIsReady when reader is closed.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to call
> CheckDataIsReady when reader is closed.    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.CheckDataIsReady(Int32
> columnIndex, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColumn, Boolean permitAsync,
> String methodName)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetFieldValueInternal[T](Int32
> i)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetFieldValue[T](Int32
> i)    at lambda_method965(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader ,
> ResultContext , SingleQueryResultCoordinator )    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
> at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncEnumerableAdapter`1.MoveNextCore()
> in
> /*/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/Operators/ToAsyncEnumerable.cs:line
> 79    at System.Linq.AsyncIteratorBase`1.MoveNextAsync() in
> /*/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/AsyncIterator.cs:line
> 77    at System.Linq.AsyncIteratorBase`1.MoveNextAsync() in
> /_/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/AsyncIterator.cs:line
> 77

My code looks like this:

```
await context.Database
    .CreateExecutionStrategy()
    .ExecuteInTransactionAsync(async cancellationToken =>
{
    var entityResult = context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking().ToAsyncEnumerable();
    var done = false;
    await using var enumerator = entityResult.GetAsyncEnumerator();
    await using var stream = new MemoryStream();
    await using var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

    var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, true);
    csv.Context.RegisterClassMap(new EntityClassMap<TEntity>());
    csv.WriteHeader<TEntity>();
    csv.NextRecord();

    while (await enumerator.MoveNextAsync()) // Cannot use foreach, because of some other stuff below
    {
        var entity = enumerator.Current;
        csv.WriteRecord(entity);
        csv.NextRecord();

        // some other stuff
    }
},
_ => Task.FromResult(true), // We are just reading, so we can always commit the transaction
System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted, // Do not block the whole table while reading. This is essentially the same as WITH(NOLOCK).
cancellationToken);
```

I think, the problem might be either small Network hickups, or the database being busy with other tasks, so what I probably need is some kind of resiliency here.
However, I cannot use the default [SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverretryingexecutionstrategy?view=efcore-6.0) because it would buffer all rows in memory which is way too much (hundreds of Gigabytes).

Comment: `IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted` does the opposite of what you assume. It doesn't *respect* locks, resulting in dirty or duplicate data, while taking a schema lock on the table. If you want to export data to a CSV, this code is wrong. Even using an ORM is wrong, as there are no Objects involved here

Comment: What are you trying to do anyway? If you want to export 100s of GBs, why not use SQL Server's `bcp` or SSIS to export the data? If you want to do this programmatically, the fast and easy way is to work with ADO.NET directly, retrieve the results with `ExecuteDataReader` and write each field out with `csv.WriteField`

Comment: If you want to avoid blocking the table use `SNAPSHOT`. It's not just that `NO LOCK` takes extra locks or returns dirty and duplicate data, it can even throw at random. You should really, really read [Using NOLOCK? Here’s How You’ll Get the Wrong Query Results.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/10/using-nolock-heres-how-youll-get-the-wrong-query-results/)  and [“But NOLOCK Is Okay When My Data Isn’t Changing, Right?”](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/08/but-nolock-is-okay-when-the-data-isnt-changing-right/)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos dirty and duplicate data is no problem in the export, as it is used for statistics in another system and a couple duplicate or wrong rows do not matter. The crucial part here is that the export itself must not aquire any locks.
`bcp` would write the data to a disk. I'm uploading it directly to Amazon S3 without writing the data to a disk first.
The overhead of EF compared to using ADO.Net here is negligible.
`SNAPSHOT` would write much data to the tempdb, because it needs to keep track at what the data looked like when the export was started.

Comment: And that is exactly what is NOT happening with `NOLOCK`. You need `SNAPSHOT`. Besides, yes, dirty data is crucial, because you'll end up reading half-written rows. Duplicate data is crucial. Random exceptions, like the one you got, is crucial. If you want to export GBs of data, it's *guaranteed* you'll run into all of these

Comment: EF is an ORM, not an ETL tool. The easy and fast way is to use the correct tools - `bcp` or `SSIS`. If you can't, you need to *minimize* the data that gets cached and that means no ORMs. The CsvHelper issue [Write to a file directly from a datareader](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1301) contains code that shows how to write directly to CsvWriter BUT an even better solution is to use `bcp`

Comment: What's the full exception? Does it contain `Could not continue scan with NOLOCK due to data movement.` anywhere in an inner exception?

Comment: There is no other exception apart from what I wrote in the question. I only cut of the part of the Stack trace that is completely in my code and leads up to the line containing `await enumerator.MoveNextAsync()`

Comment: The problem is the application code and what it tries to do. ORMs are like pickaxes. You want to move an entire truckload. EF and any ORM uses ADO.NET underneath, so no matter what you do, you're adding extra layers of needless complexity. In the end, you're reading from a DbDataReader. Your code is caching all the data into a MemoryStream too, so you gain little by using `ToAsyncEnumerable`. Why not write to the target stream directly? If you want to return a CSV from a web app, you can write to the response stream

Comment: My code is not caching all the data in a `MemoryStream`. It is getting the data row by row and writing it to the csv file row by row. So, it is reading from a network stream and writing to a network stream (the CSV file is not on the computers local disc). If it would cache everything in memory, it would crash with an `OutOfMemoryException`. It is just keeping one row of data at a time in memory.

Answer (score 1):

ORMs like EF are not meant for big ETL jobs but using NOLOCK can cause extra blocking and possibly the exception you encountered.

First of all, the use of `NOLOCK` doesn't mean the table isn't locked, quite the opposite. `NOLOCK` means `ignore locks` and actually [takes both a Share lock on the database and a Schema lock on the table](https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-impact-clr-strict-security-configuration-setting-sql-server-2017/) so it *can* cause blocking.

This also means that NOLOCK can be blocked if the table or its indexes are being modified, because these operations also take Schema locks.

If you really want to avoid blocking and getting blocked, use SNAPSHOT isolation.

All this is explained in [SQL Server table hints – WITH (NOLOCK) best practices](https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-impact-clr-strict-security-configuration-setting-sql-server-2017/) and Brent Ozar's short articles [Using NOLOCK? Here’s How You’ll Get the Wrong Query Results.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/10/using-nolock-heres-how-youll-get-the-wrong-query-results/) and [“But NOLOCK Is Okay When My Data Isn’t Changing, Right?”](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/08/but-nolock-is-okay-when-the-data-isnt-changing-right/). As Brent Ozar stresses :

> I can’t emphasize this enough: with NOLOCK, you can:
>
> - See rows twice
> - Skip rows altogether
> - See data that was never committed
> - And have your query fail with an error

**Fast Export Solutions**

The fastest solution is to use the tools offered by the database, like [bcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver16) or `SSIS`. `bcp` is a standalone command line tool that runs both on Windows and Linux.

If you have to write your own code, the fastest option is to use ADO.NET directly, read results through an IDataReader and write them out to the CSV file. This way you only load a single row at a time. The Github issue [Write to a file directly from a datareader](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1301) shows how to do this with CsvHelper :

```
await using (var db = new SqlConnection(Connection.ConnectionString))
await using (var cmd = db.CreateCommand())
{
    await db.OpenAsync();
    cmd.CommandText = @"
select *
from MyTable";
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 5 * 60;

    await using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
    await using (var writer = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(MyExtensions.TempFolder, "MyFile.csv")))
    await using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var schema = await reader.GetColumnSchemaAsync();
        foreach (var columnName in schema.Select(c => c.ColumnName))
        {
            csv.WriteField(columnName);
        }

        await csv.NextRecordAsync();

        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                csv.WriteField(reader[i]);
            }

            await csv.NextRecordAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

You can simplify this code if you use a library like [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) to reduce the boilerplate ADO.NET code :

```
using var con=new SqlConnection(...);
var sql="select * From Sales where Date>=@date";
await using var reader=con.ExequteReader(sql,new {date=DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-2)});

await using (var writer = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(MyExtensions.TempFolder, "MyFile.csv")))
...
```

Dapper will open and close the connection as needed, construct a SqlCommand with parameters that match the names and values of the anonymous parameter object, `@date` in this case.